# Please help me draw the small signal model of this circuit

Tags: small-signal

[image]

I am trying to draw the small signal model of this circuit.

I am not sure if it is correct that I connected  VB (Vbias) to the ground in the small signal model since it is a supply voltage (please correct me if I am wrong.) Should VI also be connected to the ground since it seems like a DC source because of the label “VI”?

Comment: To jbean: A  small-signal model assumes a fixed DC bias point - and it includes all elements Awhich are subject of signal changes. Hence, all DC sources must NOT appear in such a diagram. But, of course, the must be known because all the signal relevant quantities depend on the DC bias.

Comment: Sorry for some typing errors. I repeat: A small-signal model assumes a fixed DC bias point - and it includes all elements, which are subject of signal changes. Hence, all DC sources must NOT appear in such a diagram. But, of course, all DC sources must be known because all the signal relevant quantities depend on the DC conditions.

Answer (score 3):

*I'll make an argument as to why we ignore DC voltages and currents when we do analysis in small-signal, then apply the argument to your circuit. If you want a quick answer, you can scroll down to TL;DR*

When you draw the small signal of a transistor, you're effectively taking the 1st order Taylor expansion of it at an operating point with respect to independent quantities (such as Vds, Vgs, etc):

$$
I_{ds}(V_{gs}) = I_{ds}(V_{gs0}) + \frac{\partial I_{ds}}{\partial V_{gs}} \bigg|_{(V_{gs}=V_{gs0})}(V_{gs}-V_{gs0})
$$

Where the difference $$ v_{gs}=V_{gs}-V_{gs0} $$ is what we call the small signal and:
$$
g_m= \frac{\partial I_{ds}}{\partial V_{gs}} \bigg|_{(V_{gs}=V_{gs0})}
$$
Thus, we get:
$$
I_{ds}(V_{gs}) = I_{ds}(V_{gs0}) + g_m v_{gs}
$$

Which is the equivalent to say that we can quantify small signal variations around the operating point by assuming a simple slope, in this case, gm.

You can also do the same for vds, vbs, etc.

You will now realize that a small signal equivalent circuit is like placing representative small incremental quantities of your transistor (such as gm, ro, etc.)

We can reason similarly for the supply voltage Vdd. Assuming you have an ideal voltage source as a supply with a voltage Vdd (assuming you have set its "AC" voltage to 0), we can calculate a small signal parameter of it due to a change within the current through it.

$$
V_{dd} = V_{dd} + \frac{\partial V_{dd}}{\partial I_{dd}}
$$

Obviously, this partial derivative will be 0 because an ideal voltage source will remain Vdd no matter how much current is flowing through it. This 0 in the partial derivative means that we can ground it.

The same applies to VB and to the ideal current source you have on the drain. However, a 0 current source is equivalent to an open circuit. That's the reason why you don't see a current source on the small-signal analysis.

VI can be grounded depending on what you're trying to evaluate. If you want the small-signal voltage gain, then it must not be grounded. On the other hand, if you're trying to evaluate the output impedance of your circuit by placing some test voltage at the output, then it can be grounded because the output impedance will not depend on a small input signal change (it's an assumption, of course.)

Now, capacitor C appears to be placed there on purpose, so it should be kept for the small-signal analysis as well. A voltage or current variation across it will still be in terms of C, so their derivative is C, effectively.

Now, you may ask yourself, but does that mean that we can ignore any VB we might apply for the small signal analysis, since it will always be 0?

The answer is yes for small signal analysis, since you're calculating incremental changes of your circuit.

In the case of your simulator, it will also ground that voltage when you do an AC analysis, but it will have already pre-computed the gm, ro, etc. quantities of your transistor due to the different DC voltages the transistor has around.

***TL;DR:***

*VB is 0 in small signal, so it can be grounded. VDD and the current source are also 0, so they must be shorted and open-circuited, respectively. This means that the current source and supply voltage can be ignored in the small-signal analysis, since the open-circuit will isolate the grounded vdd.*

*VI must be grounded only if you're not interested in it. If you want to calculate small-signal gain, then you need it because gain is vo/vi.*

*Small signal schematic of your circuit (assuming we want to analyze the small-signal gain vo/vi:*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foBbPB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>